# Getting parent category object with SequelizeJs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model defined as:

```
var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.TEXT
       }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {


                Post.belongsTo(models.Category, {as: 'category', foreignKey:'categoryId'});
            }
        }
    });
```

And then the category model as :

```
var Category = sequelize.define("Category", {
        code: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING,
        img: DataTypes.STRING,

    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {

                Category.hasOne(models.Category, {as: 'parent', foreignKey: 'parentId'});
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see that the post belongs to one category, which can be a parent or a child category.

Each category can have only one parent category.

Now what I want is to get the parent category if it exists. I can go to N number level. However I am happy that if it works only at one level i.e.

Category - Jobs
Sub Category - IT

Now when I have a post that belongs to IT then I want to get the category object as IT but at the same time IT Category object must have an another object of Category Job record.

Currently I can only get the sub category as :

```
app.db.sequelize.models.Post.findAll({
                where: ['"Post".id = ?', postId],
                include: [

                    {model: app.db.sequelize.models.Category, as: 'category'},

                ]
            }).then(function (post) {
                res.send({post: post});
            })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Post.findAll({
  where: ['"Post".id = ?', postId],
  include: [
    { 
      model: Category, 
      as: 'category', 
      include: [
        { model: Category, as: 'parent' }
      ]
    },
  ]
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked it again however the query is running as:


" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Categories" AS "category" ON "Post"."categoryId" = "category"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Categories" AS "category.parent" ON "category"."id" = "category.parent"."parentId"  


where as I want as:

"   "Categories" AS "category.parent" ON "category"."parentId" = "category.parent"."id"

Comment: Ah yes - your parent relation should be `Category.belongsTo(Category, { as: 'Parent' })` it may not make 100% sense semantically, but what you want is parentId on the category (the source in this case)